# Accessing latest state value from different function

Tags: reactjs

How to access state value right after setting the same state variable in another function

```
     submit = () => {
       this.checkValidation();
       console.log(this.state.isError) //this is not giving updated value
    }

    checkValidation = () => {
           this.setState({
              isError: true
          })
        }
```

`checkValidation`  updates the state which I need to access inside `submit` function.

Comment: In this specific case, I'd have `checkValidation` return the result (either instead of or in addition to setting that result as state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can callback funtion to access the updated state right after setting it,

```
this.setState({ isError: true }, this.logState)

 logState = () => {
    console.log(this.state.isError)
  };
```

In your case you can either move the setting of state inside the `submit` function or return the updated the updated value from `checkValidation` function and then set the state within `submit` function :

```
submit = () => {
   this.checkValidation();
   setState(
    { isError: true },
    () => console.log(this.state.isError)
  );
}
```